# Insert comma separated string into temp table - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string which data are separated using comma(,) that i wanted to insert into temp table with id as auto increment example `string like '12,34,46,767'`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? And have you searched for `split_string()` or anything similar?  *(this question is answered literally all over the internet and stackoverflow...)*

Comment: 2012, split_string will not support

Comment: There are hundreds or thousands of sql-server-2012 user-defined implementations.  Try searching.

Comment: Here are two great articles.[Jeff Moden Splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and [Aaron Bertrand's](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) test on different methods

Answer (score -1):

Create your own split function and use it

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Ouch, this hurts my heart. You should read these two articles.[Spit strings the right way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand and [Jeff Moden's Tests](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Not my DV either, just sayin.

Comment: this is the simplest solution , i guess

Comment: Yeah using loops to split strings is a very slow approach to this problem.